# Server side font resizing

Tags: php, html, server-side

I have this PHP file that can 'create' course certificates with custom names passed through `$_GET`. 
The goal is to get the file output into any printable format and download all of the certificates in one (`.zip`) file.

The problem is that the name's width are dynamic, and the name must match `div` width.

This is a sample code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="background-image: image; background-image-size: 100% 100%; width: 1200px; height: 1200px;">
       <div class="name_1" style="width: 250px; height: 80px; margin-top: 400px; margin-left: 500px;">
            <p><?php echo $_GET['name_1']; ?></p>
       </div>
       <div class="name_2" style="width: 250px; height: 80px; margin-top: 900px; margin-left: 500px;">
            <p><?php echo $_GET['name_2']; ?></p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

I have achieved this dynamic text resizing to fit `div` width with jQuery.

The big problem is that I need to load page by page for 100+ pages to get this dynamic text re-sizing...

So, is there any way of re-sizing all the pages names and download all of them in one click?

Comment: What do you mean by "match div width"? One line reduced to fit the width or multiple lines of the same width?

Comment: @AlejandroIván One line reduced to fit the div width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the page screenshot(s) using [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) framework, documentation [here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt). It will execute the script on page load, you even have parameter to prolong time for script execution.

```
--javascript-delay (default to 200ms)
```

You have a [PHP interface](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf), but you can simply use PHP `exec` this way:

```
exec("wkhtmltopdf test.html output.pdf")
```

For creating ZIP libraries, you can find [examples here](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php).

Comment: Does not this mean that I will have to open the page to get the screenshot ?

Comment: No, this PHP library uses webkit rendering engine server side. Server will 'open' the page, render it and create a PDF. There is also wkhtmltoimage library, which creates images instead of PDF. It works great, you can even use custom fonts on page - it works!

Comment: Doesn't it mean, @VictorTello will get a rendered image, not knowing if the name fits or not?

Comment: He said he had already created script to fit text into div: `I have achieved this dynamic text resizing to fit div width with jQuery`

Comment: @skobaljic So I tested this on localhost and it works :D ! ... Sadly my host providers have `shell_exe()` deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

[FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) and its derivatives have `GetStringWidth()` method. If you use the right font, you can get it from this method. A font must be selected using `SetFont()` before calling this method. There is a set of standard fonts included (Arial, Times, Courier, Symbol and ZapfDingbats), if yours is not one of them, you have to add it: http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm

```
$string = "This is a text";
$fpdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
echo $fpdf->GetStringWidth($string);
```

Comment: `$string = "This is a text"; $fpdf = new FPDF(); echo $fpdf->GetStringWidth($string);` outputs `0`, why is that.?